# How start PowerShell from cmd by specific path

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell

I want to start **PowerShell** (C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe) from **windows 7** default command line (**cmd**) and go to the specific path.

I used the command:

```
start C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

It'll work, and show the powershell window.

But, if I use:

```
start C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe Set-Location c:\
```

The black window will flash quickly.

How can I open powershell from cmd by the specific path? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you must use the full path to `powershell.exe`, better to use `%windir%`.

Comment: Or `%SystemRoot%`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Set-Location c:\\"
```

If your path contains spaces, you can wrap it in single-quotes, like so:

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Set-Location 'c:\\program files'"
```

Comment: How can I do when the path has space? for example, path1 = c:\Program files\vim, then `> 'powershell -NoExit -Command "Set-Location ' + path1 + '"'` only can open the powershell but cannot cd in the path1

Comment: Hi, I fix that. I using two strings, `s1 = 'start C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command '; s2 = '"Select-Location ' + "'" + path1 + "'" + '"', and command = s1 + s2`. then it works

Comment: @Marslo: You can also use `'` to wrap the path. Like: `-Command "Set-Location 'C:\\Program Files'"`

Comment: Yep! Thanks @Oliver Salzburg . :) I written this for gvim. I want to press F3(or other shortcuts) will show command line (Powershell) and cd in the current file path.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Just found your answer while searching. Can you perhaps solve [my closely related problem](http://superuser.com/questions/608447/opening-powershell-at-the-current-working-directory-from-the-registry) as well?

Answer (score 3):

What Windows 10 uses in the Registry in order to open a PowerShell instance by shift-rightclicking in an Explorer window or on the Desktop ("*Open PowerShell window here*") is the following:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'
```

This can be found at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command`

Comment: Great answer, I just described this in a blog for people who are new to regedit: https://bingehacking.blogspot.com/2021/03/open-folder-in-powershell.html